# Sub-D problem with edges

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface, bevel

[image]

I want this edge to be hard, but when I try to use the bevel modifier or edge crease, this problem occurs. Also when I tried to add support edges, it still looks bad and creates other unwanted problems with the mesh.

Can you help me fix this?

EDIT: Topology

[image]

EDIT2: Curved Part

[image]

Comment: The topology is crucial for subdivision. You need to show it if you want help with it.

Comment: I just added a picture

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is switch the Outer Miter from Sharp to Arc. This will solve your problem without having to bevel any additional edges that might break curvature.

[image]

If you want to end up with geometry that's still all quads, you need manually triangulate the pre-bevel quads that buttress the bevel-weighted corners, as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome. I encourage you to check out this thread: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/gsoc-2018-bevel-improvements/440/241 There is a very active discussion going on with Howard T, the guy responsible for the bevel tool, and lots of changes are being tested out right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the bevel weights overshoot the corner by one edge. This depends on your surrounding topology. 
[image]

If they are flat then they can handle to extra bad topology but if they are curved and soft it a different matter. You will then need a denser mesh to work with and you need to do all support edges by hand. In this example I applied some levels of subdivision and used creasing to adjust the sharpness of the edges. You will sometimes need to retopo and shrinkwrap your mesh on a smooth surface to get the edges where you need them. It's laborious but the results can be fantastic.

[image]

Comment: I added a picture of the topology there, it's not flat at all :/